# Couldn't load one or more of the i18n assemblies

Tags: macos, mono, bundle

I have mono 4.6.2 on Mac OS Sierra. When I try to make bundle like this

```
mkbundle -o Test Test.exe
```

I have error

```
Couldn't load one or more of the i18n assemblies.
```

My PATH:

```
$ printenv PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51650

Comment: @SushiHangover, I have seen it. But after some action (not for solve this problem, for example install Unity 3D with mono develop) it work fine. Than I have removed mono, and install again, and now I have this error.

Bug was reported 10 days ago and nothing help from Xamarin support...

Comment: You might want to try the latest mono 4.8 preview release (mono-4.8.0.472) : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/#cross-compilation-with-mkbundle

Comment: @SushiHangover, I have installed it. And still not working. I think that problem in the paths...

Answer (score 6):

mkbundle in Mono 4.8.0 (as of Build 483) does not seem to include the SDK directory in its assembly search path by default, so it fails to find the i18n assemblies as those are the first that it tries to add to the bundle.

Simply specify the sdk directory on the command line to work around this problem

```
--sdk /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
```

Note that I only see this problem on mono 4.8, not on 4.6.2, but the same fix may be applicable. If there is no --sdk option in 4.6.2 then you could try adding the path using -L instead

```
-L /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/4.5
```

In some other places I have found suggestions to use `--cross default` to fix this issue with 4.8.0, but that seems to generate a binary that cannot be signed using codesign, whereas the use of the `-L` option does not have this problem. Using `--sdk` seems to produce an un-signable executable just like `--cross-default`

Comment: Thank you.
With use --sdk, I have other error

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gtk.Container' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2`

How I can fix it?